# Azure VM Backup failing: ExtensionSnapshotFailedNoNetwork

Tags: azure

For last several days, backup of VMs(Windows & Linux) hosted on Azure is failing with the following error:

**Error Code:** ExtensionSnapshotFailedNoNetwork

**Error Message:** Snapshot operation failed due to no network connectivity on the virtual machine.

VM has connectivity to the internet and I tried running the backup with proxy server added in Azure Agent but no luck.

Anyone faced similar issue? Thanks :-)

Comment: did you check all the scenarios mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-troubleshoot-vm-backup-fails-snapshot-timeout#snapshot-operation-failed-due-to-no-network-connectivity-on-the-virtual-machine

Comment: Yes @Aravind I checked those scenarios but couldn't get it working.

Comment: @Aravind - I found an Azure Datacenter IP Range that was missing from our NSG rules and was blocking the connection. Whitelisting the Azure range fixed our problem - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We found an Azure Datacenter IP range that was blocking the connections.

Found IP by Running TCPView(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) while running the backup for VM and whitelisting the Range in NSG Rule fixed our problem.